# Why don't the "sync blocks" reduce automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, locking

The example code below allocates a large number of sync blocks. This is displayed in Performance Monitor as "# of sink blocks in use". However after releasing the locks, the counter will not decrease until I manually call `GC.Collect()`. Why doesn't this happen automatic or isn't this a problem?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace locktest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list1 = new List<Object>();
            int threadcount = 0;
            const int maxthreads = 9000;

            for (int i = 0; i < maxthreads; i++)
            {
                var obj = new Object();
                list1.Add(obj);
                Monitor.Enter(obj); // this will initially use just a thin lock
                // lock from a different thread to move to the sync blocks table
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                {
                    Monitor.TryEnter(o, 1);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref threadcount);
                }, obj);
            }

            while (threadcount < maxthreads)
                Thread.Sleep(100); // wait until all threads have been finished

            foreach (var obj in list1)
                Monitor.Exit(obj); // release the locks
            list1.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to force GC.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            GC.Collect(); // this will reduce the number of sync blocks to almost 0
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

related: [What is a “Sync Block” and tips for reducing the count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1803298/33499)

Comment: I would *guess* the thinking is along the lines of "something that has been contended for in the recent past is likely to be contended for in the near future". Why free up a sync block if you'll need it again shortly?

Comment: This is related to a problem in a real world application where the sync blocks keep going up if running for a long time. So somehow new sync blocks keep getting created without the old ones released. A line which only goes up in Performance Monitor does not feel right. I might post a follow up question regarding that particular problem.

Comment: I can't really answer the "why", but according to Joe Duffy this is by design: http://joeduffyblog.com/2007/06/24/clr-monitors-and-sync-blocks/